# Assign values to dataset object

Tags: c#, dataset

I have values for which I want to assign it to `dataset` I tried like below but it didn't worked.

```
string strExp = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    strExp = "RAName = '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RAName"].ToString() + "'";
    DataRow[]  dr=  ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp);
}
DataSet dsNew = new System.Data.DataSet();
dsNew = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp);
```

Kindly let me know how to assign values to `dataset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not call [AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string strExp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                strExp = "RAName = '" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RAName"].ToString() + "'";
                DataRow[]  dr=  ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp);
            }
            ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges(); //Commits all the changes made to this table since the last time AcceptChanges was called.
            DataTable dtNew = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp).CopyToDataTable();
            DataSet dsNew = new System.Data.DataSet();
            dsNew.Tables.Add(dtNew);
```

The value got stored in the DataTable but select queries the committed version of the DataTable.

Comment: I am getting error as _only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement_ at line `ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges;` **Note**, I am using windows form

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Its a method - please use `()`

Comment: hi Sadiq, now getting error as _cannot implicitly convert type 'system.data.datarow ' to 'system.data.datarow'_ at line `dsNew = ds.Tables[0].Select(strExp);`

Comment: Ah - that is a datarowcollection please see my edit  - you need to call `CopyToDataTable()`

Comment: but we are taking that values in datatable, I want in dataset so that I can call it for some other purpose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118530/discussion-between-stack-and-sadiq).

Comment: hi bro, are you their ? Need one small logical help. Please help its urgent